# Help with SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to rename the columns. The syntax should be the column name between double quotes incase of two words, like this:

```
SELECT p_Name "Product Name" from items
```

So I'm trying to do it in C# code like this:

```
string sqlqry1 = "SELECT p_Name \"Prodcut Name\" from items";
```

But I get an error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'p_Name "Prodcut Name"'.
```

It seems am having somthing wrong with the quotes, but I can't figure out.

Comment: Which database: MySQL? SQL Server 2005? 2008?

Comment: I'm surprised people jump in to answer without knowing what database server it is

Comment: I'm using MS Access, I should have mentioned, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify what database you're using.  Different DBMSes use different quoting systems for identifiers (like column names).  Try:

```
 SELECT p_Name AS [Product Name] FROM items
```

or

```
 SELECT p_Name AS `Product Name` FROM items
```

which are two common systems.  Also, use the AS specifier even though some DBMSes allow you to leave it out.

(PS: In the second example, the quote character is the backtick, generally on the same key as the tilde (~) on US keyboards).

Comment: Always a pleasure to be of help.

Comment: @gbn: I tried the first statement and its working without any errors: SELECT p_Name AS [Product Name] FROM items

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `as`:

```
string sqlqry1 = "SELECT p_Name as \"Prodcut Name\" from items";
```

Comment: Rubbish. it's optional. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx it says `...[ [ AS ] column_alias ]...`

Comment: @gbn: Why are you citing microsoft docs when the OP did not specify what database he is using?

Comment: @Larry Lustig: care to bet? Does every DBMS require AS too?

Comment: Not "every" DBMS, but some do.  Why introduce possible complications while debugging?

Comment: @gbn: you're right. I don't know any database server that requires "as". DB2, MySql, Sqlite, SqlServer, Oracle, ... They all don't care